# run java program in eclipse with data input

Tags: java, eclipse, input, configuration

I seem to be able to run Java programs and get output in Eclipse when I use StdOut.println(...). I have a program that reads from StdIn and should print to StdOut. I know the program works because I have submitted it to a class autograder and got a perfect score on it, but I must be doing it wrong in Eclipse. Please explain how to set this up. I thought I understood how to use the "Run Configuration", but obviously I don't.

Comment: you can achieve it in run configurations.Go to run tab, you will find it there. You can specify running arguments there

Comment: I actually did that and specified the input. When I click Run, it appears that the program begins, but never outputs anything.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. **Right click** on the project that you want to run. (In Eclipse)
2. From the appeared menu, Select **Run As**
3. Then finally select **Java Application**

And make sure, Your console is visible in your Eclipse IDE,

To Enable it,

1. Goto **Windows** tab in Eclipse IDE
2. Then Select **Show View**
3. Finally select **Console**

Comment: I can run my application and the console is visible. At the head of the console, the name of the Class shows, but it never terminates and does not produce output...strange

Comment: @Dr.COM so can you please post your code and expected output so that we can have a look what has gone wrong.